# If the oxygen is introduced into the flammable gas by a tube, does it produce stable combustion? And What does the flame look like?

Tags: chemistry, fire, oxygen, gas

If the oxygen is introduced into the flammable gas by a tube, does it produce stable combustion? And What does the flame look like? And is the flame red in center or blue in periphery? And the shape of the flame?

Comment: This is not about Worldbuilding. Also your question is unanswerable even on the right forum ( http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ ) because you did not state which flammable gas you are referring to. Voting to close the question for being very much off-topic. .

Comment: You can see this in practice if you have access to a wood stove that uses secondary air injection to reduce emissions, or an oxyacetylene torch.

Answer (score 1):

It can. And it'll look like a normal flame of that gas.
The thing is, we introduce a finite amount of gas in a tube to an effectively infinite amount of other gas to achieve stable combustion. In this case, depending on the quantity of combustible gas (fuel) and the pressure at which the oxygen is being fed in, the gas burning will cause a change in pressure, and possibly temperature, and unless we know the quantities involved, it will be difficult to describe.

Option 1:
Low oxygen pressure: Blowback will occur and the flame will travel through the tube to the oxygen source and burn there.

Option 2:
Small amount of fuel @ low pressure: The flame will burn until there is insufficient fuel, then go out.

Option 3:
Large amount of fuel @ low pressure: If the reaction is extremely exothermic, the initial amount of fuel burning will raise the temperature, hence pressure, until it forces its way out of the container explosively.

Option 4:
Infinite amount of fuel @ low pressure: Depends on the energy output. Hydrogen = big boom; CO will burn stably.

Depending on the specifics involved, any of the above or other outcomes is feasible. You'll need to give more detail, and perhaps try https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: Is introducing oxygen into the flammable gas 
equivalent to introducing the falmmable gas into oxygen?

Comment: Please don't answer questions that you can clearly determine as being better asked on a different site in the SE network. Instead, flag the question to bring it to the attention of people with the privilege to deal with such questions appropriately.

Comment: @ZhuPeng: Assuming you've got an atmosphere's equivalent of the flammable gas and sufficient pressure of oxygen, it should be. By atmosphere's equivalent, I mean that there is enough that the marginal heat generated does not significantly affect the remainder of the gas and the fuel being consumed does not affect the pressure or partial pressure. I still recommend  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ for a more authoritative answer.

Comment: @Frostfyre: Fair enough